# Asdroid SDK Eclipse : Simple App gave Black Screen and Stopped?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

**First of all I'm totally new with Eclipse so my Code maybe full of errors ***

Second I wrote a simple App about two buttons (Add,Sub) with One TextView , the idea is about click one of these buttons and then the TextView changes and gives a number (Add=+1 , Sub = -1) ,  I'm Sure Compiler gave No Errors

But I don't know why I have a lot of problems :
1-The Apk file is not generated in the bin folder .

2-I tried to Export it using Android tools , and then tried it on my mobile and it gave black Screen then stopped working.

3-I got 3 warnings in The Activity_Main.xml about buttons and textview "Hardcoded String Should use @String Resource "

I'm totally Confused , I don't know how to fix it i tried a lot and searched on the internet but i couldn't

**Here is the  Main_Activity.Java :**

package com.example.counter;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
  int Counter = 0;

    Button A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);

    Button S = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sub);

    TextView C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Calculate);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Counter ++ ;

            C.setText("Your Total Counter Is " + Counter);

        }
    });

S.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Counter -- ;

            C.setText("Your Total Counter Is " + Counter);


    }

});
```

}}

**And here is the Activity_main.xml :**

```
<TextView

    android:id="@+id/Calculate"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"

    android:text="Waiting To Calculate"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Sub"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Add"

    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Add"

    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Calculate"

    android:text="Sub" />





<Button

    android:id="@+id/Add"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Calculate"

    android:layout_below="@+id/Calculate"

    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"

    android:text="Add" />
```

**The app suppose work even on API1 and Targeted API 17 (Jelly Bean) I tested it on Galaxy S3 Mini (have Android 4.2) and it crashed , tried simple app before with same settings and worked**

****Any Help is Appreciated , thanks for your time and Sorry for make it Long ****

Comment: Can you post your LogCat?

Comment: I am not sure but try restarting eclipse and clean project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd problem is on the `View` (e.g. `Button`, `TextView`) initialization.

Since they are declared and initialized at class scope, they are initialized before `onCreate()` (and thus `setContentView()`) is called. Because there is no layout inflated at the moment, the initialization will return `null`. Then, when `setOnClickListener()` is called, it will throw `NullPointerException` and crashes the app.

The solution is to move the initialization after `setContentView()` is called.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int Counter = 0;
    Button A;
    Button S;
    TextView C;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
    S = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sub);
    C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Calculate);

    A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Counter++;
        C.setText("Your Total Counter Is " + Counter);
        }
    });

    S.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Counter--;
        C.setText("Your Total Counter Is " + Counter);
        }
    });

    }
}
```

---

For the 3rd problem, just as Juwee posted, you can define the `String` resources to be used in XML layout file (it can be used in the code too!).

Create an XML file in `/values` folder with `<resources>` root element (or just use `strings.xml` if it's already there). Then, you can declare a string resource with String value

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="add">Add</string>
</resources>
```

Then, on the XML layout, you can refer it as `android:text="@string/add"` (Or in code as `setText(R.string.add)`)

Since this is just only a warning, you can actually ignore it. But if you decide your app to support localization, or if you use the same `String` quite often, then it is better to define it as app's resource.

Answer (score 0):

Third problem :  About this property `android:text="Sub"` ,you can define the text in the resource file "string.xml",like `<string name='subString'>sub</string>`,then make reference to it.`android:text="@string/R.string.subString"` . Have a try .